# Changes in Wordpress taking 48hrs to reflect

Tags: pages

I have changed the content in my wordpress website. it takes 24-48 hrs everytime to reflect. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your **WordPress** site is using a cache plugin (such as WP Super Cache) or a CDN like CloudFlare or Amazon CloudFront. In that case, you can manually clean the cache in order to see those changes.

You can also [force refresh without cache](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome), that will make you be able to look at the changes you just did, however, keep it mind that until the cache is clean, other visitors won't be able to see the updated version.

Comment: Keep in mind that "clearing the browser cache" in your "Force refresh" link is likely not the cause. That will only clear scripts, styles, images, etc. OP's issue would be solely contained to a file caching system at the server or plugin level (WP Super Cache, Memcached, etc.)